# can I use Spring Social with Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-security

I want to integrate the Spring Social (to provide twitter, facebook, linkedLogin) with my application in which I have already used Spring Security to provide open ID authentication....

Spring Security's open ID support is working awesome and I have tried spring social too with a sample application... Now I want to integrate the Spring Social with the original product. I want to know will this work or not..? Is Spring Security fully compatible with spring social ?

If yes, than how I need to handle the login, logout while inside the spring social's zone. What precautions I should take..?

Any blog / tutorial / source code will be of great help....

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used both of them in a project 2 months ago and they both work well together. Spring Social shouldn't give you any issue since you are requesting information to other websites (providers) without handling any authentication which is not yours.

The only tricky part is if you want to be an oAuth/oAuth2 service provider (so other websites can push/pull information from/to your website, you providing an API to a client website). Documentation is confusing, but it affects a separate namespace configured in spring security file, coexisting without overlapping with the rest of your application namespaces (multiple 'http' elements in your XML, some of them might be protected with OpenID - as Facebook would protect a status update submission form coming from another site: 'do you allow website example.com to post updates?'; others being public - as the login form used to protect the previous action).